# Loading custom attribute value in controller in Magento2

Tags: attributes, product, magento2

I'm trying to load custom attribute value in my controller but it always returns null. Here is my code:

```
public function execute()
{
    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    if(isset($product_id)){

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

        $colorGriding = $_product->getCustomAttribute('color_griding');  // returns null

        echo json_encode(array('message'=>'found', 'colors' => $colorGriding->getValue()));
    }
    else
        echo json_encode(array('message'=>'empty'));
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: No, this code is fine. I refreshed the cache and everything works now.